# How to change recurring profile page query (which gets all data)?

Tags: magento-1.7, query, recurring

I want to order the recurring profiles table data by productname and order state.
The table is currently ordered by order date.
The only option I have is change the query in the back-hand.
How do I do that and where do I find that?

Comment: order the recurring profiles page data means ? your question is not clear

Comment: @KeyurShah magento has a recurring profile page which shows all products you bought, its a table with data of your recurring profiles, they are ordered by order date but I want to order on productname, so I need to change the query in order to change the order. I don't know how to do that